# AD9833 Frequency Control Using STM32F030F4P6

Tags: function, generator, stm32

I'm using STM32F030F4P6 and Stm32Cube to run AD9833 Signal Generator.
i can generate signals.but can't change the frequency.in the Analog Devices App note there is Example:

[image: Example]

Given this example i write a code like this :

```c
void AD9833_SetFRQ(float FRQ) {
    uint32_t freq=0;
    uint32_t freq0=0;
    uint32_t freq1=0;

    freq=(int)(((FRQ*pow(2,28))/FMCLK)+1); // Tuning Word
    freq0=(freq&0x3fff)|(1<<14);  // FREQ LSB
    freq1=(freq>>14)|(1<<14);     // FREQ MSB

    AD9833_Reset();

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t*)&(freq0),1,10);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_SET);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t*)&(freq1),1,10);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_SET);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t*)&(A1),1,10);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_SET);

    AD9833_Set();
}
```

and my data output is exactly like the analog devices example as you can see in logic analyzer image :

[image: Logic1]

[image: Logic2]

Still no chance to change the Frequency.:(
what is the problem?

Comment: Please don't attach code or other question-related text as images. Just copy and paste it in, and use the various formatting facilities stackoverflow gives you. It makes like much easier for people who'd like to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry.I edited the post

Comment: Are there other commands you could use to confirm communication with AD9833 works? For example writing to some register, and then reading the value.

Comment: i can't find anything in datasheet.i don't think so!

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure control bits (e.g. DB13 resp. DB14 DB15) are written correctly?
Also, at the end, reset toggle?

Check Command sequence explained section of
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-1070.pdf